# Can a bitcoin exchange withhold your bitcoin withdrawal if you don't have the cash to take it out?

Tags: confirmations, payment, fraud

Can a bitcoin exchange withhold your bitcoin withdrawal if you don't have the cash to take it out? It's through an exchange called Fame Ex coin.